# 'Document' object has no attribute 'get_uri'

Tags: python, gedit, gnome-3

I'm working on porting some Gedit 2 plugins to Gedit 3 and I've run into the error `'Document' object has no attribute 'get_uri'` and am stumped as to what's wrong. For what it's worth, the Gedit 2 version of the plugin works.

```
def view_result(self, widget):
    # Get the selection object
    tree_selection = self.results_list.get_selection()

    # Get the model and iterator for the row selected
    (model, iterator) = tree_selection.get_selected()

    if (iterator):
        # Get the absolute path of the file
        absolute_path = model.get_value(iterator, 3)

        # Get the line number
        line_number = int(model.get_value(iterator, 2)) - 1

        # Get all open tabs
        documents = self.window.get_documents()

        # Loop through the tabs until we find which one matches the file
        # If we don't find it, we'll create it in a new tab afterwards.
        for each in documents:

# This is the line throwing the error:
            if (each.get_uri().replace("file://", "") == absolute_path):
                     # This sets the active tab to "each"
                (self.window.set_active_tab
                    (Gedit.tab_get_from_document(each)))
                each.goto_line(line_number)

                # Get the bounds of the document
                (start, end) = each.get_bounds()

                self.window.get_active_view().scroll_to_iter(end, 0.0)

                x = each.get_iter_at_line_offset(line_number, 0)
                self.window.get_active_view().scroll_to_iter(x, 0.0)

                return

        # If we got this far, then we didn't find the file open in a tab.
        # Thus, we'll want to go ahead and open it...
        self.window.create_tab_from_uri("file://" + absolute_path,
            self.encoding, int(model.get_value(iterator, 2)), False, True)
```

Additionally, I have the following import lines in my file:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio, GObject, Gedit
import os
```

I've tried looking in the Gedit 3 plugins that I already have for a similar line to see if something changed, but they have the same type of code, and neither searching Google nor StackOverflow have given me anything I can work with. I'm new to Python and doing this to learn it, so I could be missing something totally obvious, but what is it?

**Edit** `print each, type(each), dir(each)` produces the following:

```
<Document object at 0x20ea3c0 (GeditDocument at 0x21d2030)>
<class 'gi.repository.Gedit.Document'> 
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__gdoc__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__grefcount__', '__gt__', '__gtype__', '__hash__', '__info__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_get_or_create_tag_table', 'add_mark', 'add_selection_clipboard', 'apply_tag', 'apply_tag_by_name', 'backspace', 'backward_iter_to_source_mark', 'begin_not_undoable_action', 'begin_user_action', 'buffer', 'can_redo', 'can_undo', 'chain', 'connect', 'connect_after', 'connect_object', 'connect_object_after', 'copy_clipboard', 'create_child_anchor', 'create_mark', 'create_source_mark', 'create_tag', 'cut_clipboard', 'delete', 'delete_interactive', 'delete_mark', 'delete_mark_by_name', 'delete_selection', 'deserialize', 'deserialize_get_can_create_tags', 'deserialize_set_can_create_tags', 'disconnect', 'disconnect_by_func', 'do_apply_tag', 'do_begin_user_action', 'do_bracket_matched', 'do_changed', 'do_cursor_moved', 'do_delete_range', 'do_end_user_action', 'do_insert_child_anchor', 'do_insert_pixbuf', 'do_insert_text', 'do_load', 'do_loaded', 'do_loading', 'do_mark_deleted', 'do_mark_set', 'do_modified_changed', 'do_paste_done', 'do_redo', 'do_remove_tag', 'do_save', 'do_saved', 'do_saving', 'do_search_highlight_updated', 'do_undo', 'emit', 'emit_stop_by_name', 'end_not_undoable_action', 'end_user_action', 'ensure_highlight', 'error_quark', 'forward_iter_to_source_mark', 'freeze_notify', 'get_bounds', 'get_can_search_again', 'get_char_count', 'get_compression_type', 'get_content_type', 'get_context_classes_at_iter', 'get_copy_target_list', 'get_data', 'get_deleted', 'get_deserialize_formats', 'get_enable_search_highlighting', 'get_encoding', 'get_end_iter', 'get_has_selection', 'get_highlight_matching_brackets', 'get_highlight_syntax', 'get_insert', 'get_iter_at_child_anchor', 'get_iter_at_line', 'get_iter_at_line_index', 'get_iter_at_line_offset', 'get_iter_at_mark', 'get_iter_at_offset', 'get_language', 'get_line_count', 'get_location', 'get_mark', 'get_max_undo_levels', 'get_metadata', 'get_mime_type', 'get_modified', 'get_newline_type', 'get_paste_target_list', 'get_properties', 'get_property', 'get_readonly', 'get_search_text', 'get_selection_bound', 'get_selection_bounds', 'get_serialize_formats', 'get_short_name_for_display', 'get_slice', 'get_source_marks_at_iter', 'get_source_marks_at_line', 'get_start_iter', 'get_style_scheme', 'get_tag_table', 'get_text', 'get_undo_manager', 'get_uri_for_display', 'goto_line', 'goto_line_offset', 'handler_block', 'handler_block_by_func', 'handler_disconnect', 'handler_is_connected', 'handler_unblock', 'handler_unblock_by_func', 'insert', 'insert_at_cursor', 'insert_child_anchor', 'insert_interactive', 'insert_interactive_at_cursor', 'insert_pixbuf', 'insert_range', 'insert_range_interactive', 'insert_with_tags', 'insert_with_tags_by_name', 'is_local', 'is_untitled', 'is_untouched', 'iter_backward_to_context_class_toggle', 'iter_forward_to_context_class_toggle', 'iter_has_context_class', 'load', 'load_cancel', 'load_stream', 'move_mark', 'move_mark_by_name', 'new', 'new_with_language', 'notify', 'parent_instance', 'paste_clipboard', 'place_cursor', 'priv', 'props', 'redo', 'register_deserialize_format', 'register_deserialize_tagset', 'register_serialize_format', 'register_serialize_tagset', 'remove_all_tags', 'remove_selection_clipboard', 'remove_source_marks', 'remove_tag', 'remove_tag_by_name', 'replace_all', 'save', 'save_as', 'search_backward', 'search_forward', 'select_range', 'serialize', 'set_content_type', 'set_data', 'set_enable_search_highlighting', 'set_highlight_matching_brackets', 'set_highlight_syntax', 'set_language', 'set_location', 'set_max_undo_levels', 'set_modified', 'set_properties', 'set_property', 'set_search_text', 'set_short_name_for_display', 'set_style_scheme', 'set_text', 'set_undo_manager', 'stop_emission', 'thaw_notify', 'undo', 'unregister_deserialize_format', 'unregister_serialize_format', 'weak_ref']
```

Comment: Can you add this line before the error line and look at the output? :::: print each, type(each), dir(each)

Comment: @user1320237 - A quick look and change to `get_location` seems to work at the moment (I'm now getting an error for the `replace` function that follows it, due to API changes). I thought I had tried `get_location` before and it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, it was something simple. They changed `Gedit.Document.get_uri()` to `Gedit.Document.get_location()` or `Gedit.Document.get_uri_for_display()` (depending on your purposes).

For others who may be having issues finding the docs for Gedit, here they are - http://developer.gnome.org/gedit/